# Dynamic link from a text input

Tags: javascript, html, templates, hyperlink, webix

I have a text input and a link below it (I use Webix)
What I want to do is to enter a part of a link (IP address) to the text field and apply this address to a link.

I tried

```
elements:[
    { view:"text", label:'IP', name:"IPname", id:"IPid", value:"127.0.0.1" },
    { view:"template", height: 30, 
     template:"<span><a href='' onclick='"+window.open($$("IPid").getValue()+"'>Test link</a></span>" 
    }        
],
```

**But this notation doesn't work (actually, gives an error "IPid is undefined")**

My Code [Here](http://webix.com/snippet/0584e0c0)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange issue, I'm not very familiar with webix, but putting the `window.open` in a function worked. Also have in mind that the correct attribute is 'onclick' not 'click' and that a parenthesis was missing. Fixed them too, check it out:  http://webix.com/snippet/e4e236b9

```
webix.ui({
  rows:[
    {
      id:"form1", view:"form", scroll:false,            
      elements:[
        { view:"text", label:'IP', name:"IPname", id:"IPid", value:"127.0.0.1" },
        { view:"template", height: 30, 
         template:"<span><a href='' onclick='fixLink()'>Test link</a></span>" 
        }        
      ],
      width: 320,
      elementsConfig:{        
        labelPosition: "top",        
      }
    }       
  ]    
});

<script>
function fixLink(){  
  window.open('http://'+$$("IPid").getValue());
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Taking out the function was the point. For now, I improved it a bit with `<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='fixLink()'>Test link</a>` to prevent redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, I don't know whether this will help you or not, please correct me if i am wrong.

```
webix.ui({
    rows:[
        {
            id:"form1", view:"form", scroll:false,            
            elements:[
                { view:"text", label:'IP', name:"IPname", id:"IPid",   value:"127.0.0.1" },
                { view:"template", height: 30, 
                    template:"<span><a href='' id='anId' click='"/*+window.open($$("IPid").getValue()*/+"'>Test link</a></span>" 
                }        
            ],
            width: 320,
            elementsConfig:{
                labelPosition: "top",        
            }
        }       
    ]    
});

func1();
function func1() {
    document.getElementById("anId").setAttribute("href",$$("IPid").getValue());
    var abc = document.getElementById("anId").getAttribute("href");
}
window.onload=func1;
```

Comment: Solution will work with a small correstion: `setAttribute("href", "http://"+$$("IPid").getValue());`

Answer (score 0):

About you Error "IPid" is undefined occur because the declare id is not using with any control may be you do spelling mistake. If every this is fine try this code

```
 $("#YoutextBoxID").val();
```

and paste it where your request send for further activity 
Like This `click='"/*+window.open($("#YoutextBoxID").val()*/+"'`